# Duplicate results with mysql query

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I've 3 tables to query. I make a select on the first one, depending on the two others. I must have only distinct id from the 1st table, but my query is returning some duplicates... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e3d6/1

My query:

```
SELECT p.* 
    FROM posts p, blogs_subscribed s
    WHERE (p.user_id = s.user_id OR p.user_id = 1)
      AND p.id NOT IN (
      SELECT post_id 
      FROM posts_unsubscribed u
      WHERE u.post_id = p.id
         AND u.user_id = p.user_id);

SELECT p.* 
    FROM posts p, blogs_subscribed s
    WHERE (p.user_id = s.user_id OR p.user_id = 1)
      AND NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT null 
      FROM posts_unsubscribed u
      WHERE u.post_id = p.id 
        AND u.user_id = p.user_id);
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure I understand what you are looking for, but I think this is what you want...

```
SELECT p.* 
    FROM posts p, blogs_subscribed s
    WHERE (p.user_id = s.user_id OR p.user_id = 1)
      AND p.id NOT IN (
      SELECT post_id 
      FROM posts_unsubscribed u
      WHERE u.post_id = p.id
         AND u.user_id = p.user_id)
      GROUP BY p.id;

SELECT p.* 
    FROM posts p, blogs_subscribed s
    WHERE (p.user_id = s.user_id OR p.user_id = 1)
      AND NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT null 
      FROM posts_unsubscribed u
      WHERE u.post_id = p.id 
        AND u.user_id = p.user_id)
      GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: thanks. Do we have to use group by? Because the tables will be huge and I thiunk there will be a performance problem... It works with select distinct too, but I'd like to make a clean query...

Comment: Please try and edit (restate) your question, I'm not sure I follow what your asking.  Distinct might be a better choice since you do not appear to be using an aggrigators (e.g. count(*))

Comment: I've 3 tables

1: **posts**

    `id | user_id | title | post`

2: **blogs_subscribed**

    `id | user_id | blog_id`

3: **Posts unsubscribed**

    `id | post_id | user_id`


I need to list all posts from table posts where 

user_id=user_id of the owner of the blog
or
user_id=user_id of the owner blog subscribed (2bd table contains the subscribed blog_id of user_id)

and

remove posts unscubscribed (do not list them - posts owned by subscribed blogs) , contained in 3rd table (posts_insubscribed)...

I don't know if I'm clear enough...

Comment: I found a query working, but i'd like to avoid the "where in) clause... `SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.user_id in (select blog_id from posts_unsubscribed where user_id=1) OR p.user_id = 1 order by p.id DESC limit 5`